# How to use fish aliases in bash scripts

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, fish

I have a bash script and I want to use a command in it, that I defined in my `config.fish` like this:

```
alias setbg='feh --bg-fill'
```

However when I use the command in my bash script, I get:

```
setbg: command not found
```

How do I make fish aliases visible to bash scripts?

Comment: Could you just source the fish aliases in your .bashrc? Like `source alias.fish`?

Comment: By default, shell scripts don't expand aliases.

Comment: Instead of an alias, make it a separate shell script so you can put it in your `$PATH`.

Comment: Sorry, I misread this, you said you have a script, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: if bash, add this toward the top of your script:  `shopt -s expand_aliases`

Comment: The same way you run Perl code natively in a Python interpreter -- you either start a separate runtime *that knows how to interpret the language your code is written in*, or you translate that code from language-A to language-B, or you don't do it at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't.

Fish aliases are internal to fish only, and since bash and fish are incompatible it's not guaranteed you can `source` them either.

However, fish doesn't actually have *aliases*, the `alias` command is just a wrapper around defining functions, and unlike bash fish always reads its configuration.

So you can run `fish -c 'setbg'`.

Alternatively you could make a file with aliases that works in both bash and fish. As long as you stick to the common subset like simple `alias key='value'` that would work, but you couldn't use any incompatible expressions like even `if`.

Comment: Thank you for helping. `fish -c` did it.